# Add Different Data Attribute to Anchors

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to add `data-webpart` attributes to all the anchors within a document, but populate their values with the data attributes of their containing divs.

However the code I wrote appears to be populating all of the anchors with only one of the data attributes (or rather, adding the first one to all, then adding the second).

Any help would be much appreciated!

## HTML

```
<body>
    <div data-webpart="form">
        <a href="#">Test Link</a>
        <a href="#">Test Link</a>
        <a href="#">Test Link</a>
    </div>
    <div data-webpart="icon-grid">
        <a href="#">Test Link</a>
        <a href="#">Test Link</a>
        <a href="#">Test Link</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

## JavaScript

```
// data attributer
var webParts = document.querySelectorAll("[data-webpart]");
var webPartAnchors = document.querySelectorAll("[data-webpart] > a");

function addDataAttr() {
    var closestWebPartAttr;
    for (i = 0; i < webPartAnchors.length; i++) {
        for (e = 0; e < webParts.length; e++) {
            closestWebPartAttr = webParts[e].getAttribute("data-webpart");
            webPartAnchors[i].setAttribute("data-web-part", closestWebPartAttr);
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    if (webParts !== null) { addDataAttr(); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nested loops are copying the data attribute from *every* DIV to *every* anchor, because there's nothing that relates each anchor to just their parent. At the end they all have the last data attribute.

Since the anchors are direct children of the DIV, you don't need to use `querySelectorAll()` to get them, you can just use `.children()` within the loop.

```
function addDataAttr() {
    for (var i = 0; i < webParts.length; i++) {
        var webpart = webParts[i].dataset.webpart;
        var children = webParts[i].children;
        for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
            children[j].dataset.webpart = webpart;
        }
    }
}
```